# How to get only the last value of an iteration for which the iteration has converged?

Tags: r, while-loop, iteration

Please consider this while loop iteration in R

```
x=c(1,2,3,4,5)
i=2
m=x+1

m[i]=x[i]+1
x[2]=2
continue1=1


while (continue1>0) {
i=i+1
m[i+1]=x[i]+1
continue1=m[i+1]-m[i]
}
```

Now if i say print(m), it prints all the values of m produced during the iteration. I want only the last value of the iteration for which the iteration has converged. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` package and the `last` function, which it doesn't require clarifications I guess, It does essentially what the name suggests it does.

```
library(dplyr)
last(m)
[1] 6
```

and here is a base R solutions even though I have to admit that the most easy and simple is the one proposed by Blondedust in the comment (which of course I didn't even imagine before he/she posted it :) )

```
m[length(m)]
[1] 6
```